# Was a/the writer of Madoka Magica influenced by a specific anime that was broadcasting at the time?

Tags: madoka-magica

I once read the following tidbit about the development of *Mahou Shoujo Madoka Magica*, but I cannot recall the other anime involved, and I cannot find a source mentioning this.

As I recall, one of the writers or producers of *Madoka* was watching a certain anime as it was being broadcast, and it influenced them when they either wrote the script for *Madoka* or just got a certain key idea between two episodes.  This person later remarked that, had they finished watching the anime before writing anything, the plot of *Madoka* would have been much different (possibly less dark?).

Is this true, and, if so, what was that other anime?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the lead writer, Gen Orobuchi, then yes. He was [influenced](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/interest/2012-01-29/madoka-magica-writer-inspired-by-stephen-king-hidamari-sketch-nanoha-cossette) by the works of American author Stephen King and Japanese director Akiyuki Shinbo (in particular *Hidamari Sketch, Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha*, and *Le Portrait de Petite Cossette*).

Comment: But which anime influenced him in the manner described in the body of the question?

Comment: Again, [regarding](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/feature/2012-01-29) "the story of Madoka Magica, Urobuchi said that it was very strongly influenced by three of Director Akiyuki Shinbo's anime series, Hidamari Sketch, Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha, and Le Portrait de Petite Cossette." Your question itself is vague. If you are looking for something specific or something else then please better clarify what it is that you are looking for. We are unable to assertain your intent if you do not let us know what it is. We are not mind-readers.

Comment: I'm looking for one (1) specific anime that the writer was in the middle of watching when they wrote the script for *Madoka* and which the writer later stated that, had they finished watching this anime before writing the script, then *Madoka* would have been very different.  I don't know how to make that any less vague.

Comment: It seems like you want to find that one article/tidbit rather than a general answer to your generalized question. You should rephrase your question as such. We don't know what you read, not so we now if it was from an opinionated or editorialized source. Masoka has many different series and spinoff as well as different continuities. If you don't know the context, it's not very likely someone else would. A vague question will only get you vague answers